# Enable canvas mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I've got a game for mobile phones and when the user ends with it, I want him to be able to scroll down for website additional informations. Now he can't do it, because canvas is gathering all touch and another inputs :-( Game is in Pixi.js

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a transparent overlay div above the canvas using the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS selector so that the "canvas" is treated like an ordinary HTML element.

```css
canvas {
    position: relative;
    /* Other styling */
}

/* Overlay */

canvas::after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    user-select: none;
}
```

For you specifically, I would suggest adding that overlay div once the game ends so it doesn't interfere with the game mechanics.