Cannot drag within the canvas and click on objects
I have a canvas that has objects that I only need the ability to click on, the thing is that the canvas is much bigger than the container that contains it, so I enabled overflow and the option to scroll.
The problem is that through the phone you can't both scroll and click on objects, that's what I tried.
const hall = new fabric.Canvas('hall', {
    backgroundColor:'#AACFE1',
    selection: false,
    width: 2000,
    height: 1500,
    controlsAboveOverlay: true,
    centeredScaling: true,
    allowTouchScrolling: true
});

CSS:
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .hall-canvas {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 390px;
        height: 800px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

I also attach a picture for a better illustration:
As I said, I want both the option to click and to scroll, and the canvas simply resists any scrolling or moving action except clicking


Can you add your html code?

Of course, this is the part of the canvas.



This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75747458/23456704              Or try to move overflow: scroll;
be defined on the canvas tag itself and not on its wrapper.

I tried and unfortunately it didn't work
